# "Take the 2-minute tour" button is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

> [image]

The urr, title says it all really... and if you were still confused, I'm pretty sure the picture explains it.

But if you're *still* confused... the "Take the 2-minute tour" button, which is shown for logged out users is too big for the container it sits in.

Answer (score 2):

That's a huge button for sure! I've pushed a fix to dev, it will be live after our next production build(within 24 hours)